# How to push element in a array of inside array in mongoose doc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I cant solve this problem. Help me. 
My `conversation` Schema this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate')
const User = require('./user')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const conversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  groupName: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  messages: [Object],
  recipients:[{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
  }],
  admins: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }]
},{timestamps: true});
conversationSchema.plugin(findOrCreate)

const Conversation = mongoose.model('conversation', conversationSchema);

module.exports = Conversation;
```

and these when I update message and update reader. Problem here I cant really good update readers:

```
await Conversation.findByIdAndUpdate(current._id, {$push: { 
                messages: { 
                    sender, 
                    text, 
                    date: dt,
                    remove: [],
                    readers: []
                } }})
```

I cant good solve this but I cant do it. I want `push` user._id in readers array or `remove` array. Now I try add readers.

```
await Conversation.updateMany( { _id: _id }, {messages: { readers: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$eq: user}}} }}, { messages: { $push: {readers: user } } } )
```

Comment: Did you create a schema for the messages? Subdocuments and paths need a schema defined too.

Comment: I dont think about it. If you have idea please write

Comment: I do this. But I get another problem. When user create Conversation messages is empty array. But if I use subdoc how to do this?

Comment: Read up on subdocs and how they are used. Mongoose docs are good about this. Btw, I'd also suggest messages be in their own collection, as they are unbounded. MongoDB documents have a max size of 16MB. That is a lot of data, but you really shouldn't be coming close to filling it, which with a long conversation, you'd have. So, don't use subdocs, use a ref to the conversation on the messages.

Comment: This is good Idea. I will do this